# Get only 1 Most Recently Modified Child Post from Parent

Tags: wp-query

I have 2 custom post types:

1. Drama
2. Episode

Drama is Parent, and Episode is child. Now, for instance I add 2 dramas and and then add episodes (Drama 1, Drama 2 as Parent):

**Drama 1**

1. --- Episode 1
2. --- Episode 2 ** updated
3. --- Episode 3
4. --- Episode 4 ** updated

**Drama 2**

1. --- Episode 1
2. --- Episode 2
3. --- Episode 3
4. --- Episode 4
5. --- Episode 5
6. --- Episode 6
7. --- Episode 7 ** updated
8. --- Episode 8 ** updated

** updated shows the episode was recently updated.

On Homepage, I want to display all posts from "Episode" post type order by post_modified. So with above example it shows the following on homepage:

Sorted by post_modified..

1. Episode 8 - Drama 2
2. Episode 7 - Drama 2
3. Episode 2 - Drama 1
4. Episode 4 - Drama 1
5. Episode 1 - Drama 1
6. Episode 3 - Drama 1
7. Episode 1 - Drama 2
   ..
   ..
   ...

It displays all 12 episodes ordered by post_modified.

**THE PROBLEM..**

Since I have only 2 Dramas, I want to display only 2 most recently updated episodes from those dramas (only 1 post from every parent), I dont want to show all episodes. So the desired output on homepage should be only following 2 episodes:

- Episode 8 - Drama 2
- Episode 4 - Drama 1

I used WP_Query to display episodes, however it displays all posts. How can I limit episodes and get only 1 most recently updated episode from each Drama.

```
 $wp_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'episode',
    'orderby' => 'post_modified',
    'order'   => 'DESC',
    'suppress_filters' => true,
    'posts_per_page' => 100,
    'paged' => $paged
    
 ));
```

Edit - Update: Rephrased and removed another similar question.

Edit 2: The number of Dramas and Episodes are just for example, the actual number of Dramas is over 20K and Episodes over 300K.

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe you don't need Wp_Query. I believe you can just do

```
$episodes_for_front_page = array();

//get the two dramas
$dramas = get_posts(array('post_type' => 'drama'));

foreach ($dramas as $drama){
  
  //get all the episodes belonging to that drama, sorted by most recent update
  $episodes = get_posts(
    array(
      'post_type' => 'episode',
      'post_parent' => $drama->ID,
      'orderby' => 'post_modified',
      'order' => 'DESC'
    )
  );

  //add the most recent episode to the list of posts to display
  $episodes_for_front_page[] = $episodes[0];
}
```

Comment: Thanks but this may bot work, as I posted number of episodes and dramas as an example, the actual posts under Dramas are more than 20K and under Episodes over 300K, secondly with this I cannot get the most recently updated Episode, it will just query Dramas first but infact Episodes are the ones which are updated/added.