# Adding GROUP BY in Custom Query not working with ORDER BY

Tags: wp-query

Below is my query

```
 $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type='episode' GROUP BY post_parent ORDER BY post_modified DESC  LIMIT 32;");
```

it doesn't sort with post_modified DESC, but if I remove GROUP BY post_parent, it perfectly displays all recently updated posts. Is there any way to handle this ? Following query works if I remove GROUP BY...

```
 $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type='episode' ORDER BY post_modified DESC  LIMIT 32;")
```

Comment: [GROUP BY](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) will group all rows with the same value into a single result, usually used for counting number of X in Y (people in countries for example), Thats why you get 1 result or none. What are you trying to achive with group by?

Comment: Have you tried using `WP_Query` instead? Querying the posts table with raw SQL is extremely rare in WordPress and normally considered a mistake in all but the most exceptional of circumstances. `WP_Query` supports various sorting mechanisms, and integrates with plugins and filters such as caching plugins or tools such as elastic search, as well as priming posts by fetching secondary data to avoid lots of tiny queries such as post meta and terms

Comment: @Buttered_Toast - I am using GROUPBY to get only 1 post from each parent post (most recently updated post from parent)

Comment: @TomJNowell - I am struggling with 2 custom post types, which I cannot get the most recently updated child (only 1 post from parent).. This was my actual question, I didnt any any answer so I thought I would go for custom query instead
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/391208/get-child-parent-sorted-by-child-update-modified-time

Comment: @Themer I tried to read your other question but could not understand what you were asking, you should edit your question to make it clearer and easier to understand so that people can answer it

Comment: Also there are filters for group by on `WP_Query`

Comment: @TomJNowell - I agree, my other question might be confusing, basically I want to retrieve only 1 recently updated post from each parent (Drama). I tried to rephrase my question below, thanks for your time.. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/391264/get-only-1-most-receently-updated-child-post-from-parent

Comment: @Themer stop opening duplicate questions, you can edit your original question to improve it